# not able to access the JSON object in handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

I am new to handlebar.js. i want to access the Home.Names.Id while am iterating through Home.Room in handlebar template.

but am getting empty value.

```
{{#Home.Room}}

   {{Home.Names.id}}

{{/Home.Fip}}
```

am i missing anything here? I need your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this:

```
{{#x}}
    {{y}}
{{/x}}
```

Handlebars will be looking for `y` inside `x` so the data would need to look like this:

```
x: { y: ... }
```

or like this:

```
x: [ { y: ... }, { y: ... } ]
```

If you want to look for `y` in the namespace above `x`, you can say `../y`:

```
{{#x}}
    {{../y}}
{{/x}}
```

In your case:

```
{{#Home.Room}}
   {{../Home.Names.id}}
{{/Home.Room}}
```

I'm assuming that the `Fip` in your question is just a copy'n'paste typo BTW.

Demo (open your console): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/NCUnP/